# File not found exception :access is denied running on apache tomcat 7.0

Tags: java

I run a Java Application by using Apache Tomcat 7.0. I want to write files to another ftp server. The ftp file path is saving in a text file (//192.168.100.3/ftp/Testing).

When I start tomcat from bin>>tomcat.exe, the file is really written to the Ftp server.

When I start tomcat from services.msc, the following error occurs: File not found exception : access is denied

Comment: //server/share/path looks like a windows share not like a ftp server

Comment: You confuse readers by saying that you write files to an ftp server when what you do seems to be to write to a Windows share on a machine that may have ftp in its name. 1) What exactly are you trying, ftp to a server or just write a file to share? 2) Provide a stack trace that you certainly get. Make sure to format it nicely as code.

Answer (score 0):

Execute services.msc as an **administrator**.

I assume one of the invoked files is in a subdirectory of `Program Files` and thus needs special permissions to be run.